# StackNavigator inside TabNavigator add headerRight button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am unable to add a headerRight button to my component.

I have a StackNavigator:

```
const profileNavigator = StackNavigator({
Profile: {
    screen: PFProfileAuthenicate,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Profile',
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.primaryInput
        }
    }}
});
```

inside of a TabNavigator:

```
const iosTabs = TabNavigator({
Profile: {
    screen: profileNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/face.png')}
                style={[styles.icon, {tintColor: tintColor}]}
            />
        )
    }
} [...other tabs]
}, {
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
});
```

The authenticator component is just rendering this:

```
render() {

    if (this.props.authStore.isLoggedIn)
        return <PFProfile navigation={this.props.navigation}/>;
    else
        return <PFLogin/>;
}
```

I am trying to add a right `save` button to the header in the PFProfile component.  I've tried [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons.html#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component) and everything else I can find.

I'm thinking it has something to do with how the component in question isn't actually defined in navigator but nothing I've tried has been able to make this work.

I'm new to all this.  Am I setting everything up right?  Is that the best way to render the login vs. the profile?  Any help would appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: One hacky way can be to use headerMode: 'none' in your Profile stack and then put a header View manually at the top of PFProfile component

Comment: @MukeshSoni yeah, I'm not a giant fan of that idea

Comment: @PritishVaidya I've edited my question, I can't add a button or menu to the nav bar in my stacknavigator

Comment: @PritishVaidya - thanks for your answer.  I'm still new to all this, I'm using Mobx so I'm looking into a Mobx solution like you describe.  I've confirmed that the problem is when I use the conditional to render <PFProfile> then <PFProfile> has no navigation prop (except the one I pass to it and that one doesn't recognize the `navigationOptions` when I declare it in PFProfile.  I wish there was a way to just `replace` the <PFLogin> with <PFProfile> in the render when the auth prop returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Just gonna put this out here and y'all can tell me if it's totally off the wall:

You see above how I passed the navigation object from PFProfileAuthentication to PFProfile?

Well, in PFProfile I do this (and it works):

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    if (this.props.navigation.state.routeName === 'ProfileAuthenticator') {
        this.props.navigation.replace('Profile');
    }
}
```

Now PFProfile is in the stack and my navigationOptions are applied to the header so my button shows up.

Comment: Looks fine, as long as it helps you solve your problem, I'm am unclear about the navigation structure and the components layout, therefore I've decided to delete my answer.